Why does EIP-155 add two extra zeros to the encoded transaction?
Quoting the EIP:

[...] instead of hashing only six rlp encoded elements (nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data), you SHOULD hash nine rlp encoded elements (nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, chainid, 0, 0).

Adding the chain id for replay protection makes sense, of course. But what's the purpose of the two extra zeros?

The two extra zeros are placeholders for the r and s values of the ECDSA signature. These values are initially set to zero when the transaction is being signed. The r and s values are part of the signature that proves the transaction was signed by the owner of the private key. After the signature is calculated, the actual r and s values are inserted into the transaction, replacing the zeros. This mechanism allows for the transaction to be signed without knowing the r and s values in advance, which is necessary for the signature process.
Example:
Let’s say we have a transaction that needs to be signed. Before signing, the r and s values of the ECDSA signature are initially set to 0. Here’s how the transaction might look:
Original transaction:
[nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, chainid, 0, 0]

The r and s values are initially set to zero. After the transaction is signed, the actual r and s values are calculated and inserted into the transaction, replacing the zeros.
Signed transaction:
[nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, chainid, r, s]

